# PowerPoint VBA - some pieces of code runs not in order (MsgBox, Sleep etc)

Tags: vba, powerpoint, sleep

VBA - 7.1. PowerPoint 2013

I am trying to achieve a small animation for an image on a slide (hide - wait half a sec - show).

I had noticed earlier that MsgBox usually pops up before the previous line of code gets completely executed. While it was annoying, I did't bother about it much. However, same behavior with Sleep is making my approach falls apart. I don't know how the system process management (or threads or whatever) is done internally by PowerPoint but it seems to have some problem.

I have tried following so far

### 1:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

Sub SleepTest()
ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide 1").Shapes("Worker").Visible = 0
Sleep 5000 'delay in milliseconds
ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide 1").Shapes("Worker").Visible = 1
End Sub
```

Resut:-> Nothing happens. Before visibility is set to 0, sleep kicks in, wait for 5 seconds, image hides and shows within a millisec (so you cant see it happened)

### 2:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

Sub SleepTest()
ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide 1").Shapes("Worker").Visible = 0
MsgBox("temptemptemp")
Sleep 5000 'delay in milliseconds
ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide 1").Shapes("Worker").Visible = 1
End Sub
```

Result: -> MsgBox pops up immediately, after few seconds while msgbox is shown, the image hides, click ok, application waits for 5 secs, image is shown back.

### 3:

I tried putting hiding and showing steps in two different subs and tried calling second sub after the sleep. It also showed the same behavior as the first attempt.

Can anyone provide some explanation for this behavior? Or suggest any other way to achieve what I am trying for.